# open decompiler view of current module (dll) in dynamic analysis

Tags: ida, debuggers, dll

I have a program (P.exe) with several dependencies (A.dll, B.dll etc). I decompiled and studied B.dll, but at runtime, P.exe is using A.dll. The horizon is updating in ISA view-RIP, but I don't have the decompiler view.

How can I get the decompiled view of A.dll, where the horizon is ?

Using IDA pro 7.5

Comment: What do you mean by “horizon”?

Comment: Horizon or RIP, ie., where the execution is located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to take a snapshot of the process memory and then work with it since it includes the modules.

Another is to create a database with all the modules, as described: https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/several-files-in-one-idb-part-3/